# CRON expression for Azure Webjob

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I am trying to run my Webjob in schedule manner and i need it to run it during weekdays between 7 AM - 6PM. I was able to do add the start time but couldn't figure out how i would tell it to stop running after 6PM.

This is what i got so far:

> 0 0 7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following expression. This will run hourly for hours 7 to 18 on weekdays

```
0 * 7-18 * 1-5
```

proof:

```
https://crontab.guru/#0_*_7-18_*_1-5
```

so you use range (int-int) to define a range in cron, in this example you need to use 7-18 to run from 7am to 6pm

Comment: well..i don't want it to run hourly, it needs to run continuously between 7-18 time, during weekdays. hope that makes sense.

Comment: well, you'd have to start it at 7 and kill at 18. these are triggers, not time limits. The schedule is completely ignored in continuous WebJobs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734388/azure-scheduling-a-webjob that guy works on web app team